# Class wrapper and dispatcher

Tags: c++

Suppose i have class A.

I want to write some kind of wrapper that will wrap some functions, add some new functions and all other functions dispatch to A class. And want it to look naturally in client code. I think it requires some kind of introspection and might be impossible in C++, but maybe I am wrong.

ADDED after Cody Gray comment:

I have class a for print in rect. It has methods SetX, SetY, SetDX, SetDY and gettes, and many other. I want to create class that will also have methods SetBaseX, SetBaseY and wrap SetX, SetY according to given Base, but dont want to wrap DX methods. And also dont want to use inheritance to prevent casting from wrapper class to A. I have not only A, so wrapper must be able to wrap many classes which implement some interface.

Comment: Why would it require introspection? Wrapper classes are written in C++ all the time... Perhaps post some pseudo-code indicating what you'd like to do?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to manually write delegating wrappers for all functions of of the wrapped class. There is no introspection in C++ that would allow you to automate this.

Comment: yap, bad news, will search for other solution)) +1

Answer (score 2):

You want to use composition.

Class B is the wrapper for class A. Class B instantiates class A in its constructor and deletes it in its destructor, so B is responsible for A.

Class B declares its own methods and the methods of class A, and when one of A's methods is called it dispatches it to the local class A variable and returns the result.